# Access remote database federation DB2

Tags: db2

I have 2 systems. system A and system B and both are DB2 servers. I want to be able to access system B database from system A. Both have a database called `TESTDB`. I am trying to run the following command to create a server.

```
CREATE WRAPPER "drdawrapper"
   LIBRARY 'libdb2drda.so'
   OPTIONS (DB2_FENCED  'Y'
     );
```

```
db2 "CREATE SERVER "PRD_SERVER_SSL_FLEX" TYPE DB2/UDB VERSION '11' WRAPPER "drdawrapper" AUTHORIZATION "xyz" PASSWORD "xyz" OPTIONS (DB2_CONCAT_NULL_NULL 'Y',DB2_VARCHAR_BLANKPADDED_COMPARISON 'Y',DBNAME 'TESTDB',HOST '169.62.253.230',NO_EMPTY_STRING 'N',PORT '50001',SECURITY 'SSL',STRING_UNITS 'S');"
```

But I keep getting:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL1101N  Remote database "TESTDB" on node "<unknown>" could not be accessed 
with the specified authorization id and password.  SQLSTATE=08004
```

Node directory:

```
db2 list node directory

 Node Directory

 Number of entries in the directory = 1

Node 1 entry:

 Node name                      = TESTNODE
 Comment                        =
 Directory entry type           = LOCAL
 Protocol                       = TCPIP
 Hostname                       = 123.21.23.12
 Service name                   = 50001
```

The credentials are correct. I am not sure what `node` is it looking for. Any pointers?

Comment: Node is referring to the result of a CATALOG NODE command. Take care of your " - you might want to escape it with \" inside the outer most ""

Comment: I did catalog node using `CATALOG TCPIP NODE testnode REMOTE 123.21.23.12 SERVER 50001`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about configuration than programming.

As you appear to be encrypting the federated connection it can be wise to *first* verify that the encrypted connection works at the command-line, separately from federation. This irons out a lot of the detail and is easier to troubleshoot.  After you get that working, you can then begin on encrypting the federated connection.

Please follow the detailed instructions [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0070301.html) (choose the correct Db2-version):

You have to know in advance which kind of SSL/TLS trust verification you want (i.e. either single cert (client trusts the server - simplest and easiest), or multiple certs (both sides trust the other - more setup, arguably more secure), because this determines the configuration.

Ensure both of your Db2 instances and databases are properly configured for SSL.

Catalog the remote-node locally with security SSL (`db2 catalog tcpip node ... remote ... server ...security ssl`)

Catalog the remote-database locally on the new node name (`db2 catalog database ... at node ...`) followed by `db2 terminate` .

Verify a command-line connect to the remote database using the federated credentials, using the configured `db2dsdriver.cfg` if using SSLSERVERCERTIFICATE method, or using the keystore/stash configuration ( `db2 connect to remotedb user ... using ...` ). Use the same userid/password that you will use later in the `create server` command.

Once that command-line connect works, you can proceed with the encrypted federation link, via  `db2 create wrapper...` and `db2 create server...`.

There's no need to use quotes around the wrapper name, just let it fold, otherwise quotes are just annoying redundant noise, although it is not a mistake.

Inside the script for `create server` command options instead of `AUTHORIZATION "xyz" PASSWORD "xyz"` use `AUTHORIZATION \"xyz\" PASSWORD \"xyz\"`   (i.e. escape the quotes).

For one-sided trust, use `SSL_SERVERCERTIFICATE` in the `create server` options clause and ensure the value is accurate (fully qualified path to the remote-db2instance-certificate-file), and that the file/directory permissions are valid.

For mutual trusts, use both `SSL_KEYSTORE` and `SSL_KEYSTASH` keywords with correct values, in the `create server` options clause (having previously ensured your keystores are properly populated, as verified by a command-line connect above).

You may also want to consider `create user mapping` depending on the requirements.

Finally you can create your nicknames, and test out the federated  link by querying those nicknames.